# Passing Fake data as parameters to NUnit test method

Tags: c#, nunit, faker

I am using NUnit with C# and Faker.NET Library, Is there is any way to pass fake data generated by Faker.NET as a parameters for my test method?

Edit:

```
public static object[,] GetInvalidLoginCredentials()
    {
        object[,] FD = { { new object[] { Name.First(), Internet.Password(10, 12) }, new object[] { "TestUser", "" }, new object[] { "", "TestPassword" } } };
        return FD;
    }

 [Test, Order(1), TestCaseSource("GetInvalidLoginCredentials")]        
    public void InvalidLogin(string userName, string password)
    {
         // Test case code 
    }
```

When running this test, The test runner runs it only 2 times:-

- The first one with parameters `("","TestPassword")`
- The second one with parameters `("TestUser","")`

And Ignores running the test with parameters from the first object in the data source array that its values are generated using Faker.Net

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Of course you can pass any object as parameter. What is the problem here?

Comment: [TestCaseSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute)

Comment: If you give a more specific question, with a code example of what you are trying to achieve it makes it easier for someone to give a more precise answer with a code example.

Comment: When I Try to pass parameters using TestCaseSource attribute with a static field or method returning fake user name and password as a data source the test runner ignores running the test case with these fake data, However if I Explicitly set the values of the data source the test case runs normally

Comment: Please show some code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: And Ignores The first object of the data source array which their values are generated using the Faker.Net library

Comment: And sorry I Do not know how to format my code in a comment

Comment: @Liam I Edited it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `NUnit` related (and not `Fake.NET`) and occurs when a [generated testname](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Generation-of-Test-Names-Spec) includes any arguments that have values that can change between runs.

The testcase below (*not using `Fake.NET`*) would suffer from this same issue, as the `DateTime` changes each time.

```
new object[] { DateTime.Now.ToString(), "TestUser" }
```

The (display)name of this test would be: `InvalidLogin("11/12/2018 20:10:59", "TestUser")` but `InvalidLogin("11/12/2018 20:15:59", "TestUser")` when 5 minutes later.

One way to solve this is by assigning a fixed name to the test, which doesn't include these dynamic parameter values.

To do so, change the return type of the `GetInvalidLoginCredentials`from `Object[,]` to `IEnumerable<TestCaseData>`.

The [`TestCaseData`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) class has the `SetName` method to overrule the name of the test.

Your `TestCaseSource`method above would look like below, where the 'ignored' test will now have a fixed name `InvalidLogin-WithFakeData`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetInvalidLoginCredentials()
    {
        TestCaseData[] FD = {                 
            new TestCaseData(Name.First(), Internet.Password(10, 12)).SetName("InvalidLogin-WithFakeData"), 
            new TestCaseData("TestUser", ""), 
            new TestCaseData("", "TestPassword")                
            };

        return FD;
    }
```